# Can IE AutoComplete width be configured?

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, autocomplete

Can the width of the "AutoComplete" popup be configured in IE? (Version 11 or Edge)

The width of the popup is too narrow in some instances, as illustrated by the screenshot below:

[image: AutoComplete popup is too narrow]

**EDIT1: Minimal example added**[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

If you are using the [AutoComplete in Internet Explorer 11](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/4028663/windows-internet-explorer-11-turn-autocomplete-on) and [HTML  autocomplete Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp), you could try to set the textbox width property, the autocomplete popup width is depends on the textbox width, you could check this sample:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" style="width:300px;" name="lname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

If you are not using the above method to display the popup, please post the related code.

Comment: Thanks. I've added an example to the original question. It appears the popup width does depend on the width of the textbox, but with a MINIMIUM width of 95px.